# Converting a sql term into cake php

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to convert "left(SchoolCode,1) = '1'" which is in the sql i was provided into a correct field for the fine where statement. I am not a sql expert here but have been looking through cakephp documentation and can't seem to find a solution. any help would be appreciated.

The app i am creating, basically has a first screen where it shows the current year and 4 check boxes each with elementary middle and high. so if elementary is selected and submit is pressed then it executes that statement below giving back all  records.

```
select     *
from        MMSD.vSchoolFromCalendar
where    FiscalYear = 2019
and    DistrictCode = 'MA'
and    summerSchool = '0'
and    left(SchoolCode,1) = '1'

public function getElementary()
{
    $query = $this->find()
    ->where([
        'FiscalYear' => '2019',
        'DistrictCode' => 'MA',
        'summerSchool' => '0',
        'left(SchoolCode,1)' => '0',
    ]);
    return $query->toArray();

}
```

My result should return the data with "and    left(SchoolCode,1) = '1'" as a selected where field which right now it does not.

Comment: Might it just be because your code is comparing to `'0'` there instead of `'1'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getSchoolsByLevel(string $code = '0', string $isSummerSchool = '0')
{
    $query = $this->find()
    ->where([
        'FiscalYear' => $schoolYear,
        'DistrictCode' => 'MA',
        'summerSchool' => $isSummerSchool,
        'SchoolCode like' => $code,
    ]); 
    return $query->toArray();
}
```